# Is it possible to compile MonoTouch projects with languages other than C#?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

How would I go about using F# or J# for instance?  I'm not sure what to get to grips with in the project's compiler settings.

Is there a sequence of command line steps I could follow to compile a MonoTouch project that I might interpret to replace the C# step but tell the other compiler to use the correct platform details etc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. In the book "[Developing C# Apps for iPhone and iPad using MonoTouch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430231742)" you could see text ([proof](http://books.google.ru/books?id=lFe0EwHUREEC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=monotouch%20%20only%20.NET%20language%20available%20for%20writing%20MonoTouch&source=bl&ots=-SPiq1F-V5&sig=tAXMCLLRC9mdUF5UJXPPLuWmZoY&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=LQZgULfiGrPP4QTk6YCwDg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=monotouch%20%20only%20.NET%20language%20available%20for%20writing%20MonoTouch&f=false)):

***C# Is Currently the Only Language***

*Additionally, currently, the only .NET language available for writing MonoTouch applications is C#.*

Nothing changed since that book publication.

Comment: C# Is Currently the Only **supported** Language. People are doing quite a few different things, including using Java with **IKVM** and postprocessing assemblies. The variations are endless (and generally quite complex) and it's why we are, at the moment, only supporting C#.

Answer (score 2):

Maxim Korobov is right, MonoDevelop only supports C# when writing for MonoTouch.

But this is not the whole truth: MonoDevelop also has (preliminary) support for Portable Library Projects (PLP). What this means is that you can create and compile PLP projects in Visual Studio (in any language Visual Studio supports for PLP projects), and then reference that library in MonoDevelop. Just have in mind that the PLP support is preliminary right now, and you might run into a few bumps on the way.

Comment: Good additional commentary to the answer.  Thank you!